Asset Browser: How to save an armature pose including custom properties values?
I have a character rig. Some bones includes custom properties, that appears at the side bar and can be adjusted in the Item tab to control some extras.
When I create a pose for my asset library, the custom properties values are not saved, just the bone poses.
Is this basically impossible or is it my mistake?
Thank you

Hello, maybe you want to save the entire collection as an asset instead ? If you just mark the armature as an asset I think it will only serialize its own custom properties, not the bone childs custom props.

My intention was to switch a pose inside the scene as a variation. Saving the whole collection is a global solution to share between scenes or users, but it doesn't fulfill my needs to switch the pose quickly inside the project scene.
